# Using Process32First/Next inside DLL procedure

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll

I have the following procedure:

```
procedure MyMainThread.MapProc;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  PID: dword;
  Struct: TProcessEntry32;
  Processes: TStringList;
begin
  Handle:= CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  Struct.dwSize:=Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
  Process32First(Handle, Struct);
  Processes:= TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    Processes.Add(Struct.szExeFile);
    Processes.SaveToFile('C:\Log.txt');
    PID:= Struct.th32ProcessID;
    PIDHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
      PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
    CloseHandle(PIDHandle);
  until (not Process32Next(Handle,Struct));
  Processes.Free;
end;
```

As you can see, I save the running processes inside C:\Log.txt, and this works nice when inside an .exe file. Now I'm trying to implement this inside a .DLL file, and the concept is: The DLL will be loaded, and it will have an EntryPoint calling a Thread.Create... This Thread will use a SetTimer to run the procedure MapProc every 10 seconds to save the running processes in C:\Log.txt. The code is:

```
library Project1;

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Registry,
  EncdDecd,
  TLHelp32,
  IdHTTP;

{$R *.res}
type
  MyMainThread = Class(TThread)
  var
    DestDir, ContactHost: String;
    Sent: TStringList;
    PIDHandle: THandle; //need to be public because we use in MapProc / CatchYa
  private
    procedure MapProc;
    procedure MapMemory(ProcessName: string);
    procedure CreateMessagePump;
  protected
    constructor Create;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor MyMainThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  Priority:= tpNormal;
end;

procedure MyMainThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      SetTimer(0, 0, 10000, @MyMainThread.MapProc); //setting timer 10 seconds calling MapProc
      CreateMessagePump; //we are inside DLL so I think we need Message Pump to timer work
      Terminate;
    end;
end;


procedure MyMainThread.MapProc;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  PID: dword;
  Struct: TProcessEntry32;
  Processes: TStringList;
begin
  Handle:= CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  Struct.dwSize:=Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
  Process32First(Handle, Struct);
  Processes:= TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    Processes.Add(Struct.szExeFile);
    Processes.SaveToFile('C:\Log.txt');
    PID:= Struct.th32ProcessID;
    PIDHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
      PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
    if POS(Struct.szExeFile, ExeName) = 0 then
      MapMemory(Struct.szExeFile); //procedure called for verification purposes, but it's not even getting called
    CloseHandle(PIDHandle);
  until (not Process32Next(Handle,Struct));
  Processes.Free;
end;


procedure MyMainThread.CreateMessagePump;
var
  AppMsg: TMsg;
begin
  while GetMessage(AppMsg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(AppMsg);
      DispatchMessage(AppMsg);
    end;
  //if needed to quit this procedure use PostQuitMessage(0);
end;


procedure EntryPoint(Reason: integer);
begin
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
    begin
      MyMainThread.Create;
    end
  else
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, 'DLL De-Injected', 'DLL De-Injected', 0);
    end;
end;

begin
  DLLProc:= @EntryPoint;
  EntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

But when running this, I get in the Log.txt file only the line: [System Process]

The exe hosting DLL is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HD: THandle;
begin
  HD:= LoadLibrary('C:\Project1.dll');
end;

end.
```

Comment: That code works exactly the same in a DLL as it does in an EXE. The different is presumably in the host. What is the DLL's host? Of course, you don't perform much error checking, and you leak a handle every time you call the function.

Comment: You are overwriting your output file in the loop. The code you shown will not function properly within application too. Show a real code.

Comment: The DLL is hosted in a suspended explorer.exe process...
And yes, the loop is overwriting but I'm sure it shows only [System Process], and it works properly in application... Just try it...

Comment: No, I think you are going to need to try things. Try making your own host that uses the DLL. That will convince you that the issue is the host and not the fact that the code is in a DLL.

Comment: I just created a new application and the only thing it is doing is `LoadLibrary('C:\Project1.dll');` 
But the Log.txt file created in C: contains only: [System Process]... Don't know what to do...
@OnTheFly man i'm telling you I'm using Delphi 2010 and it's compiling and working perfectly here. What you want me to do? Solve your problem because you can't run? I have a problem here that i'm trying to solve, unfortunately no time to solve yours... All that people giving minus points in the question don't even know the problem...

Comment: I don't believe you. I suggest that you provide an SSCCE. Instead of getting upset by the downvotes, fix your question. Make an SSCCE. It's that simple.

Comment: The problem is explained in the question. I have a DLL file, with that procedure, and it's getting only [System Process] as running... When I run the same code in EXE file I get all processes running. I tried creating a new .exe that do a LoadLibrary in the same DLL, and it still getting only [System Process], one say the procedure don't work even in EXEs when I'm running in EXEs and I see it working... Another say it is working and I'm lying about a problem that don't exists... Thank you, I'm done.

Comment: **You** are making us to solve **your** problem right here.

Comment: Well, nobody else can observe the same behaviour as you. So, if we cannot see it, how can we help. Like I said, provide an SSCCE. Now, I suspect that the issue is related to your injection mechanism. Are you calling the function from DllMain perhaps? I don't know. I can only guess. If you just gave us an SSCCE, you'd get an answer I'm confident.

Comment: You complain that the people voting you down don't know the question. But that's the whole point! They're voting you down because you have not effectively communicated your problem, which makes this a poor question. People don't vote because they don't know the answer. They vote because they don't know the *question*.

Comment: I added few notes there... This is all I have information that can involve the problem...

Comment: When we take your code, put it in a DLL, export `MapProc`, and then call `MapProc` from a host exe, it behaves fine. And that's to be expected. What does it matter whether the code is in DLL or EXE? So, if you want help, you'll need to make it clear what the environmental difference is between our understanding of the problem, and yours.

Comment: I think the problem is the thread. Because when I created another executable doing only LoadLibrary, I did not called MapProc from the executable. I just created a thread in DLL's entry point, and in this thread I call the MapProc... So it's running directly from DLL, not exported and being called from executable... I think the DLL thread is running in different "layer" of the other threads in Windows and can't capture the processes running... Makes sense?

Comment: Why do you save the list within the loop?

Comment: Please supply the SSCCE. It should be possible in 20-30 lines of code. All you need is the DLL project. Cut down everything that's not needed. We can write our own host that simply calls `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: As I see, OP still refuses to fix obviously a bug I've discovered in the very first comment :-) I'd say this Q is not recoverable. Should go into the Trash and new **sane** question should be made.

Comment: Question was remade. Refresh it, I just edited with all the informations.

Comment: Please supply the entire file, cut down, starting with `library` and ending with `end.`.

Comment: The file have around 500 lines with lots of procedures / functions that don't even are called/involved in this problem... Why I should post the entire file man?

Comment: Cut the file down. Make an SSCCE.  Do you know what an SSCCE is? And also, I suspect that it will help for us to see your test host exe. Does it by any chance call LoadLibrary and quit immediately?

Comment: No, as I said my host exe is the explorer.exe created suspended... I'll paste the entire file cutting the procedures / functions that are not involved the problem... and I'll paste how I create / inject the dll inside explorer.exe process... Check it in 5 min please.

Comment: No, you said *I just created a new application and the only thing it is doing is LoadLibrary('C:\Project1.dll');* That's the host. Don't expect us to inject into out explorer process.

Comment: I post everything in the question now. I wanted to avoid this because now the question is so big... Anyway everything is there, if no sufficient to try solve the issue, I think is something on my compiler...

Comment: You don't need `TranslateMessage` for this loop, it's for keyboard input.

Comment: Problem with the compiler, eh, User? Reminds me of this: https://twitter.com/channingwalton/status/371539345439617024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that your code fails is that you're not using a proper callback for the `SetTimer` function. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that should have a signature like

```
procedure (hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR; dwTime: DWORD); stdcall;
```

Your incompatible callback - which is a class method - causes the code to think the `Self` lives at a completely arbitrary memory address, as class methods has an implicit Self parameter but winapi has no knowledge of that. Now when the code tries to write to an invalid address - 'PIDHandle', assuming there should be a class field, an AV is raised and since the exception is not handled the rest of the code is not executed - also as explained in David's answer.

Your solution is to use a proper callback. To access class members you can use a global variable. Not using a global variable would require some hacky code (google for MethodToProcedure f.i.)

A sample could be like:

```
threadvar
  MyThread: MyMainThread;

procedure TimerProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR; dwTime: DWORD);
  stdcall;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  PID: dword;
  Struct: TProcessEntry32;
  Processes: TStringList;
begin
  Handle:= CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  Struct.dwSize:=Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
  Process32First(Handle, Struct);
  Processes:= TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    Processes.Add(Struct.szExeFile);
    Processes.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\Log3.txt');
    PID:= Struct.th32ProcessID;
    MyThread.PIDHandle:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or
      PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PID);
    if POS(Struct.szExeFile, ExeName) = 0 then
      MyThread.MapMemory(Struct.szExeFile);
    CloseHandle(MyThread.PIDHandle);
  until (not Process32Next(Handle,Struct));
  Processes.Free;
end;

procedure MyMainThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      MyThread := Self;
      SetTimer(0, 0, 10000, @TimerProc);
      CreateMessagePump;
      Terminate;
    end;
end;
```

To take David's advice, not to get beaten by the '@' operator, we should first redeclare the `SetTimer` function to use the callback correctly. That would look something like:

```
threadvar
  MyThread: MyMainThread;

procedure TimerProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR; dwTime: DWORD);
  stdcall;
var
  ..
begin
  ..
end;

type
  TFnTimerProc = procedure (hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UIntPtr;
      dwTime: DWORD); stdcall;

function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent: UIntPtr; uElapse: UINT;
  lpTimerFunc: TFNTimerProc): UINT; stdcall; external user32;

procedure MyMainThread.Execute;
begin
  MyThread := Self;
  SetTimer(0, 0, 10000, TimerProc);
  CreateMessagePump;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Well done. And yet again the use of the @ operator proves fatal. Don't do it people!! I did notice this error but for some reason did not think it was the problem. I think I had not spotted that the handle was not a local variable.

Comment: @user Sertac has done well here, and I'm happy that you accepted his answer instead of mine. It is the answer to your question. However, I would still recommend that you stop using a timer and use a synchronous sleep based approach as proposed in my answer. It's really a much simpler way to solve your problem. And as I've said so many times here on SO, and not just to you, but also to others (including, famously, Sertac himself!), using the @ operator to generate procedural variables is a recipe to generate pain. You've suffered twice now! Don't make it three!

Comment: When I try to do: `SetTimer(0, 0, 30000, MyMainThread.MapProc);`
I get error saying: This form of method call only allowed for class methods...
I tried some other ways but always getting error... So I leave the @...

Comment: user - David's point is, when you don't use '@', you won't get it to compile unless you supply a correct callback. What you supply is incorrect, hence it doesn't compile. Getting it to compile is not the goal, since it will later can cause problems as we've seen here. However, it requires declaring the function that use the callback correctly in the first place. That's not the case for winapi declarations in RTL. That's why I'm reluctant to take @David's advice, not that I disagree with him. Anyway let's do it..

Comment: @user1526124 The fact that you shut the compiler up with the use of  `@` may have given you a warm feeling, but it does not mean that you solved the problem. You just said to the compiler, "I don't care what you say, do it my way even if my way is wrong". Sertac does correctly point out that the declarations of Winapi callbacks in the `Windows` unit are rubbish and do lead you towards the `@` operator. But the latest update that Sertac made shows how to avoid that. Of course, now you have multiple declarations of `SetTimer`. Basically, Emba screwed up and don't have the balls to fix it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You've done a lovely job here. I'd upvote again if I could!

Comment: Yes, I understand what you guys says... I'm not experienced in coding, my skills not that good as you can see in my posts... And this thing about coding DLL using classes like timers, idhttp, tstringlist don't look a good idea... Is there anyway to easily create a DLL and implement all this classes like ttimer (not even the need of using settimer), and all others I said above? Maybe creating a invisible form and adding all this classes inside the form... Any idea?

Comment: Well, my opinion is that you should not do any of that. I think the code at the bottom of my answer is the simplest way to get something to happen every 10s in your injected DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that works as you'd expect. This proves that process enumeration using toolhelp32 works perfectly well from a DLL.

**Library**

```
library ProcessEnumLib;

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows, TlHelp32;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  PID: dword;
  ProcessEntry: TProcessEntry32;
  Processes: TStringList;
begin
  Handle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  Win32Check(Handle<>0);
  try
    ProcessEntry.dwSize := Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
    Win32Check(Process32First(Handle, ProcessEntry));
    Processes := TStringList.Create;
    try
      repeat
        Processes.Add(ProcessEntry.szExeFile);
      until not Process32Next(Handle, ProcessEntry);
      Processes.SaveToFile('C:\Desktop\Log.txt');
    finally
      Processes.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
end;

begin
  TMyThread.Create;
end.
```

**Host**

```
program ProcessEnumHost;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;

begin
  LoadLibrary('ProcessEnumLib.dll');
  Sleep(1000);
end.
```

Your version is failing because the call to `OpenProcess` is raising an access violation which is killing the thread. Right now, I'm not sure why that is so.

I suggest that you simplify grossly. You don't need a message loop, and you don't need a timer. You can use `Sleep` in your thread to pause between process maps. Something like this:

```
library ProcessEnumLib;

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows, TlHelp32;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Handle, ProcessHandle: THandle;
  ProcessEntry: TProcessEntry32;
  Processes: TStringList;
begin
  while True do
  begin
    Handle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    Win32Check(Handle<>0);
    try
      ProcessEntry.dwSize := Sizeof(TProcessEntry32);
      Win32Check(Process32First(Handle, ProcessEntry));
      Processes := TStringList.Create;
      try
        repeat
          Processes.Add(ProcessEntry.szExeFile);
          ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID);
          CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
        until not Process32Next(Handle, ProcessEntry);
        Processes.SaveToFile('C:\Desktop\Log.txt');
      finally
        Processes.Free;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(Handle);
    end;

    Sleep(10000);//10s sleep
  end;
end;

begin
  TMyThread.Create;
end.
```

I've no idea why, but this variant avoids the AV when calling `OpenProcess`. I'd love to know why. But it's the right way for you to do what you want, and it side-steps the problem.

Comment: Yes thank you, but as you can see, after the OpenProcess I'm calling another procedure, and that's the point. I need to do this... How to use OpenProcess, any idea?

Comment: No I do not. Yet. At least we are on the same page now. I have to say, I think you've been very unhelpful here. Anyway, I'll try to work this out.

Comment: It's not about you, but every time I create one question here, I start receiving minus from people that don't even try to answer. This looks like fun here, and that other guy saying the procedure don't works, as you can see the procedure works... And I'm on Win x64, maybe you are too... If the DLL is x32 I think we can't do OpenProcess on x64 processes... That can crash the thread... Or no?

Comment: As Rob said, the problem was that we could not answer because we did not know the question.

Comment: I think the difference with 'working' and not 'working' is not timer vs. sleep, but PIDHandle (ProcessHandle in your code) being a class field vs. local (or global, or threadvar). I mean, the api (OpenProcess) has no problem, it's assigning to the LHS that's raising.

Comment: And where you think PIDHandle need to be? I'm using it in 2 procedures from TThread class... I think if global, it will be very problematic once it's accessed from thread. If local from MapProc procedure, I can't access in the other one... Any idea?
_EDIT: I put the var PIDHandle as global and it looks like working now with OpenProcess... Is there any problem to let it global once it's accessed from one thread?_

Comment: @user - Make it local to MapProc and pass it to MapMemory with a parameter.

Comment: @user1526124 Parameters are always the first choice