# Infinity loop on Message Queue

Tags: delphi

I'm working with a injected DLL inside another process. In this DLL I create one Thread to among other things set 2 Timers and do a KeyboardHook (SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL)... To make this hook and the 2 timers work, I needed to create one Message Pump procedure. And I call this Message Pump as the last thing on my Thread, as you can see in my Thread.Execute:

```
procedure MyMainThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      MyThread:= Self;
      StartKeyboardHook;
      StartUp;
      SetTimer(0, 0, 60000, @MyMainThread.ContactHome);
      SetTimer(0, 0, 40000, @MyMainThread.MapProc);   
      CreateMessagePump;
      Terminate;
    end;
end;
```

Ok, after the CreateMessagePump call, I do a Terminate, because I believe that the Message Pump is one infinity loop, and if I get out from that, something wrong occurs so I need to terminate my Thread. The CreateMessagePump is on this:

```
procedure MyMainThread.CreateMessagePump;
var
  AppMsg: TMsg;
begin
  while GetMessage(AppMsg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(AppMsg);
      DispatchMessage(AppMsg);
    end;
  //if needed to quit this procedure use PostQuitMessage(0);
end;
```

I'm doing this the correct way? I mean, is correct to believe that this loop is infinite?

Comment: The only way out of that loop is GetMessage retrieves a WM_QUIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop in your `Execute` method is pointless. Since the final act of the loop body is to call `Terminate` then the loop body can run only once. Write it like this:

```
procedure MyMainThread.Execute;
begin
  MyThread:= Self;
  StartKeyboardHook;
  StartUp;
  SetTimer(0, 0, 60000, @MyMainThread.ContactHome);
  SetTimer(0, 0, 40000, @MyMainThread.MapProc);   
  CreateMessagePump;
end;
```

Your message loop is just fine. Some people may warn you to check the return value of `GetMessage` more closely, but your usage is actually fine. See Raymond's discussion of this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx

---

It's not clear, but it seems plausible that what you are passing as the timer procedure is not compatible with the required function signature. The declaration of `SetTimer` in the `Windows` unit results in no type checking being performed on the callback that you pass. Which means that you can pass absolutely anything. The fact that the compiler compels you to use the `@` operator is the warning sign that you have a problem.

The way out is to stop using the `@` operator, and use a fixed declaration of `SetTimer`. You should use the code that Sertac provided in one of your earlier questions: [Using Process32First/Next inside DLL procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473938/using-process32first-next-inside-dll-procedure/18477917#18477917).

Comment: David, I remember you, always saying me to remove the @ from the SetTimer, is a shame that it still there... But I really tried to remove without success, every time I got a new damn error when I tried to remove that '@'...

Comment: I can show you how to do it if you want. Sertac already showed you with a different API call. You just need to declare a `SetTimer` that has a sane declaration of the type of the callback proc.

Comment: @user - You've got a more serious problem than '@', you're passing a method to TimerProc.

Comment: Yes I tried to use the Sertac declaration, but it didn't worked... @Sertac - what's the more serious problem than the @?? confused...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That would be alright if `MyMainThread.ContactHome` was a static class method. This is indeed the problem with using `@`.

Comment: @David - Ok. Didn't think of that possibility. Indeed one would be certain without the @.

Comment: Okay guys, I'll accept David's answer and finish this question. Anyway I believe I'll need to come back here in few days because I have a problem with the SetWindowsHookEx, I'll explain this in another question... For while I'm trying to fix.. Hope you two can help-me again, thanks again.

Comment: @user - We've discussed it then. [TimerProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) have a specific declaration. The callback you supply must conform with that.